# Using std::sort() without prefix "std" and also without "using namespace std;" compiles successfully

Tags: c++, stdvector

As `sort()` is defined in `namespace std` it must always be used as `std::sort`.But the following code compiles correctly even without `std`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums = {4,3,1,7,2,0};
    sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());
}
```

[ideone.com](http://ideone.com/IUSuBQ)

But this code doesn't.

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{

    std::array<int,5> nums = {4,1,8,9,6};
    sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());
}
```

Using `gcc 4.8.4` with `-std=c++11` flag enabled.

From both these code snippets it is clear that `std::vector` has something to do with this.But I can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm thinking argument-dependent lookup.

Comment: Note that the second example _will_ compile with MSVC, because it provides custom iterators for `std::array`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). If you use `typeid` to examine the types of the iterators involved:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::cout << typeid(std::vector<int>::iterator).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(std::array<int, 5>::iterator).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

at least on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/aMQBao), you get the following output:

```
N9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiSt6vectorIiSaIiEEEE
Pi
```

With Revolver_Ocelot's help in the comments, we see that these types are `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >` and `int*`.

For the vector, after the usual name lookup fails, the compiler searches the `__gnu_cxx` and `std` namespaces for a `sort` function, `__gnu_cxx` because it's the namespace of `__gnu_cxx::normal_iterator` and `std` because it's the namespace of one of the template arguments, `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >`. It finds `std::sort`.

For the `std::array`, the iterators are just `int*`s, so argument-dependent lookup searches no additional namespaces and finds no `sort` function.

Comment: "_I'm not entirely sure how to read that_". It is `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >` and `int*`. Not that it helps much...

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot different namespaces. Probably the `sort` is defined in __gnu_cxx.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Hmm. It's not apparent to me why ADL for that would look in the `std` namespace. This may require more digging than I know how to perform to trace exactly what's happening.

Comment: Oh, wait, it's looking in the namespaces of the template arguments.

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/n5Rnhe)'s another way to get the types (in the error message).

Comment: Thanx to all.Learned new things.

Comment: Related: With MSVC, the iterator types are instead `V?$_Vector_iterator@V?$_Vector_val@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@std@@` (`class std::_Vector_iterator<class std::_Vector_val<int,class std::allocator<int> > >`) and `V?$_Array_iterator@H$04@std@@` (`class std::_Array_iterator<int,5>`); due to `std::array` using a custom iterator, ADL is enabled for it.

Answer (score 2):

This is *argument dependent lookup.* According to Stroustroup's *The C++ Programming Language: 4th Edition*, there are two rules that apply here:

> 1) If an argument is a member of a namespace, the associated namespaces
>   are the enclosing namespaces.
>
> 2) If an argument is a built-in type, there are no associated namespaces.

In your first and second cases, begin() and end() return iterators. However, the C++ standard defines an iterator as any variable of any type, upon which an iteration operation can be performed. (In other words, an iterator is a design concept that is enforced via a *template*.)

According to the other answer, the iterators in the first case are variables of a data type that belongs to the same namespace as sort(). However, the iterators in the second case have a primitive data type. Per Rule #2, these iterators have no associated namespace.

Comment: Explanation, why it worked in first case and didn't in second, would make answer better.

Comment: "_expected to each return iterators - i.e, variables of the "iterator" type_". No, they are expected to return something adhering to _RandomAccessIterator_ concept. A raw pointer does adhere to that concept.