# Unqualified sort() -- why does it compile when used on std::vector and not on std::array, and which compiler is correct?

Tags: c++, c++17

When calling `std::sort()` on a `std::array`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> foo{4, 1, 2, 3};
    sort(begin(foo), end(foo));

    std::array<int, 4> foo2{4, 1, 2, 3};
    sort(begin(foo2), end(foo2));
}
```

Both gcc and clang return an error on the sort on the `std::array` -- clang says

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'sort'; did you mean 'std::sort'?

Changing to `std::sort(begin(foo2), end(foo2))` fixes the problem.

MSVC compiles the code above as written.

Why the difference in treatment between `std::vector` and `std::array`; and which compiler is correct?

Comment: `sort(...` --> `std::sort(...`. I *guess* that ADL (argument dependant lookup) is what's tripping you up. That, or deduction guides. In any case; *always* qualify the functions you call.

Comment: Could be that the MSVC library have some specialization of `std::sort` that leads to [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (like you already have for `std::begin` and `std::end`)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's simply that all of the containers in VC++'s stdlib use class type iterators defined in `namespace std` even where a simple pointer type would have worked. I believe this is to insert debug-build checks to detect overruns and other common errors.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is comes down to the type that `begin` and `end` result to and how that works with [Argument Dependent Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup).

In

```
sort(begin(foo), end(foo));
```

you get

```
sort(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator)
```

and since `std::vector<int>::iterator` is a member of `std` ADL finds `sort` in `std` and the call succeeds.

With

```
sort(begin(foo2), end(foo2));
```

You get

```
sort(int*, int*)
```

and because `int*` is not a member of `std`, ADL will not look into `std` and you can't find `std::sort`.

This works in MSVC because

```
sort(begin(foo2), end(foo2));
```

becomes

```
sort(std::_Array_iterator, std::_Array_iterator)
```

and since `std::_Array_iterator` is part of `std` ADL finds `sort`.

Both compilers are correct with this behavior.  `std::vector` and `std::array` don't have any requirement on what type is used for the iterator except that it satisfies the [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) requirement and in C++ 17 for `std::array` that the type also be a [LiteralType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType) and in C++20 that it be a [ConstexprIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ConstexprIterator)

Comment: I guess the question is whether MSVC's behavior is conforming, i.e. does the `std::array` iterator *have* to be `int*` or can it be a class type? Similarly for `std::vector` it would be relevant to the question whether the iterator *has to be* a class type on which ADL will work, or whether it can be `int*` as well.

Comment: @walnut It can be whatever the implementation wants it to be.  It could be a `std::iterator`, something else, or just a pointer.

Comment: I also wonder why in this library implementation they chose to use `int*` for `std::array` but not for `std::vector`.

Comment: The iterator types for both `std::array` and `std::vector` are unspecified, meaning the implementation is allowed to define them as raw pointers (code won't compile) or class-type wrappers (code will compile only if the class type has `std` as an ADL associated namespace).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No idea.  Personally I like that `std::vector` use a "real" iterator and `std::array` use a pointer but that's just my preference.  As long as it supports the random access requirements it doesn't really matter what it is.

Comment: `std::vector<int>::iterator` isn't necessarily a member of `std`. [Last I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491995/using-stdsort-without-prefix-std-and-also-without-using-namespace-std-c), it was a member of `__gnu_cxx` on the GCC setup I tried it on, and the ADL looked in `std` for other reasons.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica `iteratror` is a member of `vector` and `vector` is a member of `std` so `std::vector<T>::iterator` is a member of `std`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That only applies if `std::vector<T>::iterator` is actually a nested class, rather than an alias for a class not actually nested in `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: [Here's a demo](https://ideone.com/Qx9lyd) where the ADL fails with an alias, and [here's a demo](https://ideone.com/U5SIkr) where the ADL succeeds with a nested class. Both here and in my earlier tests, `std::vector<T>::iterator` is an alias.