# Why does std::sort() without prefix "std" not compile in Visual Studio 2010 when using a lambda?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda, argument-dependent-lookup

I have encountered a situation where a call to `std::sort()` works without explicitly writing the namespace. According to [Using std::sort() without prefix "std" and also without "using namespace std;" compiles successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491995/), the compiler uses ADL and considers the namespaces of the arguments. Since `vector` is in `std`, it finds `std::sort`.

In the following program, ADL fails for the second call to sort when using Visual Studio 2010. Since the iterators are the same, `std::sort` should be findable. But the compiler says `C3861 'identifier': identifier not found`. Why?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class StableSortClass
{
public:
  int m_i;
};

bool lessStableSortClass(const StableSortClass & lhs, const StableSortClass & rhs) {return lhs.m_i < rhs.m_i;}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::vector<StableSortClass> vec;

  // works because of ADL without std::
  sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), lessStableSortClass);
  
  // does not compile in Visual Studio 2010
  sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const StableSortClass & lhs, const StableSortClass & rhs) {return lhs.m_i < rhs.m_i;});

  // compiles
  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const StableSortClass & lhs, const StableSortClass & rhs) {return lhs.m_i < rhs.m_i;});

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

To answer the comments so far:

1. I don't want to rely on ADL. I found code in a header and wondered why the compiler does not complain to the missing `std::`. I then noticed that the `std::` is sometimes required and sometimes not, hence this question.
2. `C3861 'identifier': identifier not found` is the complete error message the compiler gave to me. Nothing more.
3. Yes, some folks do maintenance for old production systems where VS2010 is used. It could be worse ;-)

Comment: Why are you using the VC++ 2010 compiler?

Comment: The support for C++11 in VS *2010* should be expected to be a bit spotty.

Comment: Also, never rely on ADL when the relevant arguments are iterators - they could suddenly be raw pointers if you change compiler or even just compile flags. (Some libraries have custom vector iterator classes in debug mode, but raw pointers in release.)

Comment: I expect the complete error message to tell more. Always read the complete error message, `C3861 'identifier': identifier not found` is only the generic part which isnt very useful

Comment: btw in some sense `std::sort` has ADL enabled only by coincidence. If you wanted to call a different sorting method, you'd just call it rather than rely on ADL.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I think this advice is good only for containers with continuous memory, so: std::vector, std::basic_string, std::initializer_list std::array c-array and views on those containers: std::basic_string_view std::span

Comment: @MarekR That's already a lot. And I think it's good advice in general to not rely on ADL when you don't control the argument types exactly.

Comment: There is also `std::ranges::sort` which can't work with ADL (extra level of namespace), at least `begin` `end` becomes obsolete. Also `projection` feature is quite cool (even for example from question).

Comment: Your 2 `sort` should compile/not compile the same way with ADL on the iterators.

Comment: *"is the complete error message the compiler gave to me. Nothing more."* There are several panes: "Errors list" which is a resume, and "Build Output" which might have additional information.

Comment: @Jarod42 I checked those places. It baffles me too that the output is so terse.